# Python/OpenCV: Why is cv2.StereoBM not working in this case?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

**Case 1:** This code runs fine:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)
imgR = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM(0, ndisparities=16, SADWindowSize=15)
stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)
```

**Case 2:** But this fails on the last line:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 1)
imgR = img[:,:,2]
imgL = img[:,:,1]

stereo = cv2.StereoBM(0, ndisparities=16, SADWindowSize=15)
stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)
```

The error says:

> error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/calib3d/src/stereobm.cpp:802: error: (-211) SADWindowSize must be odd, be within 5..255 and be not larger than image width or height in function findStereoCorrespondenceBM

The *really* strange thing is that it fails with the same message even if I put following two lines right in front of the `imgR =` and `imgL =` starting lines, i.e.:

```
img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 1)
img[:,:,2] = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)
img[:,:,1] = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)
imgR = img[:,:,2]
imgL = img[:,:,1]
```

I'm still quite new to Python so maybe its a misunderstanding: Can somebody explain why case 1 works but case 2 gives me an error?

Comment: Check the size of imgL and imgR - `print imgL.shape, imgR.shape`, maybe they are different or equal to 0. Also try to use some other version of OpenCV - 2.3.1 is 3,5 years old, why don't you use latest stable version - 2.4.10 or eventually beta (3.0) ?

Comment: The issue is not replicable  in version 2.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in old OpenCV version.

Part of OpenCV 2.4.4 changelog:

> Numerous bug fixes, and optimizations, including in: blendLinear, square samples, erode/dilate, Canny, convolution fixes with AMD FFT library, mean shift filtering, **Stereo BM.**

Most likely using 2.4.4 or any higher version (I suggest that you use the latest stable release) will solve your problem.

Comment: You were right, its reproducable with OpenCV 2.3.1 but not with OpenCV 2.4.8. Its a shame that 2.4 is not available on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Try to build it from source, on you own - it should not be hard. OpenCV uses cmake so you will be able to configure everything using simple, but nice gui and cmake will handle most configuration stuff. I've done this several times on Windows (which is not the most build-it-from-source-frienly OS ;)) and it was quite simple.